# Maximo Anywhere - Cannot deploy apps remotely to mobilefirst server( Rest Exceptions)

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am trying to deploy Maximo Anywhere apps from MacOS X system using ./build.sh command. It is always failing with:

```
Resexception: unexpected response, Not able to access <an URL>
```

I am not able to understand what is causing this issue.
The mobile first server is deployed in a Cloud server.
Please let me know if you have faces this issue.

Below is the error log I can see:

```
8/7/18 16:32:45:610 AEST] 000000bc WASRuntimeMBe I   SOAP connection with port number 8879
[8/7/18 16:32:45:610 AEST] 000000bc WASRuntimeMBe I   Establishing SOAP connection on *actualserverName* with port number 8879
[8/7/18 16:32:57:985 AEST] 00000096 WorklightILMT I com.worklight.core.ilmt.WorklightILMTLogger dumpLicense FWLSE0277I: Creating an ILMT record in the file 'D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgAppSrv01\logs\worklight\caffeda003ba82a720f5f584f060728a.slmtag'. [project MaximoAnywhere]
[8/7/18 16:32:59:126 AEST] 0000005a ProjectManage I com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl logTransactionDetails FWLSE0275I: Starting transaction with ID 14 for 'deployAdapter'.  [project MaximoAnywhere]
[8/7/18 16:33:00:891 AEST] 0000005a StatusMessage E StatusMessage createStatusMessage Preparation to deploy adapter failed: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while accessing MobileFirst artifact URL: https://*aliashostName*:443/wladmin/otu/1.0/28656effffffd52effffff871bffffffc759ffffffc4ffffffb3ffffffee70377b3f/runtimes/MaximoAnywhere/downloads/adapters/Temporary317569284
                                 java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while accessing MobileFirst artifact URL: https://*aliashostName*:443/wladmin/otu/1.0/28656effffffd52effffff871bffffffc759ffffffc4ffffffb3ffffffee70377b3f/runtimes/MaximoAnywhere/downloads/adapters/Temporary317569284
    at com.worklight.common.util.HttpUtil.getBytesFromURL(HttpUtil.java:630)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagementServiceBean.readAdapterContent(AdapterManagementServiceBean.java:181)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagementServiceBean.deployAdapter(AdapterManagementServiceBean.java:112)
    at com.worklight.mgmt.impl.AdapterManagementImpl.deployAdapter(AdapterManagementImpl.java:52)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.deployAdapter(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:1488)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:292)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:206)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:188)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:130)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:67)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:250)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:151)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:265)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:832)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$QueuedWork.run(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1987)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    at com.worklight.common.util.HttpUtil.getBytesFromURL(HttpUtil.java:627)
    ... 32 more

[8/7/18 16:33:00:970 AEST] 000000af BaseTransacti E   Result: MaximoAnywhere: worklight/ctgCell01/ctgNode01/172.23.100.7: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while accessing MobileFirst artifact URL: https://*aliashostName*:443/wladmin/otu/1.0/28656effffffd52effffff871bffffffc759ffffffc4ffffffb3ffffffee70377b3f/runtimes/MaximoAnywhere/downloads/adapters/Temporary317569284
[8/7/18 16:33:01:001 AEST] 0000005a ProjectManage I com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl logTransactionDetails FWLSE0275I: Starting transaction with ID 14 for 'reject'.  [project MaximoAnywhere]
[8/7/18 16:33:01:079 AEST] 000000af BaseTransacti I   Result: MaximoAnywhere: worklight/ctgCell01/ctgNode01/172.23.100.7: Rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere that you're not supposed to deploy the apps to the real server from a local, remote environment. Is there a team administrating the server on the Cloud? If so, I would recommend providing the Cloud Team with your (perhaps) updated application folders and asking them to perform the deploy for you, from the server itself.